# Understanding exactly how vpn encryption works

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn

We have a site to site vpn setup with a cyber roam cr35ing on one end (and 10mbps up/down dedicated line) and a sonicwall TZ215 on the other end (with 50mbps up/down). The main purpose of the tunnel is to reroute all traffic (and essentially act as a tunnel) from the cr35ing to the TZ215 since specific websites our company uses are restricted by IP.

Currently with an IPSEC tunnel we are getting about 3mbps up/1.4mbps down on the cyber roam end. I am thinking of switching over to PPTP or no encryption even to check if it's possible to increase the speeds further.

My question is, if I disable encryption, the tunnel should essentially work like a normal day to day connection correct? Any and all input on this matter will be appreciated.

Comment: pptp is not as secure as ipsec, if you disable encryption your transfer speed you should be greater than with with encryption.

Comment: ok, but what I am trying to understand is if I don't have encryption does that mean the data can be intercepted and possibly changed while being sent and received between the sonicwall and cyber roam devices? Or will browsing the web for example be the same as browsing the web without a vpn, (http is un encrypted like usual and https is encrypted) and for example would accessing a banking site or sites of that nature be a security issue?

Comment: if you don't have encryption, then traffic will be encrypted... i'd assume you only tunnel private ip, not everything, banking sites are on https.

Comment: We have to tunnel all of our traffic from one location through to another (unless there is away we can filter certain websites to be accessed through the tunnel) since a few of our company sites have back ends that can only be accessed from a specific ip, mainly our head office ip.
VPN is completely new territory for me and I was having trouble understanding the way encryption worked. Essentially by turning VPN encryption off the connection would work like a normal internet connection but with the traffic going through the tunnel; am I correct?